# On a summation in "Artin's conjecture for primitive roots" by Heath-Brown

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, quadratic-residues, primitive-roots, character-sums

This is a question on the paper: D. R. Heath-Brown. *Artin's conjecture for primitive roots*. Quarterly J. Math. 37 (1): 27–38, 1986.

At the beginning of the proof of his main theorem on page 35, Heath-Brown states (here $q, r, s$ are multiplicatively independent non-square integers such that $-3qr, -3qs, -3rs, qrs$ are all not squares): "for a fixed integer $n$, not a square, one has
$$
\sum_{p \leq X} \left(\frac{n}{p}\right) = o(\pi(X)), \quad \text{ as }X\rightarrow\infty
$$
If we let $n$ run over the $16$ numbers $(-3)^eq^fr^sg^h$, where $0 \leq e, f, g, h \leq 1$, then $n$ cannot be a square if $e+f+g+h$ is odd, by the hypothesis of the theorem. Hence
$$
\sum_{p \leq X} \left(1-\left(\frac{-3}{p}\right)\right)\left(1-\left(\frac{q}{p}\right)\right)\left(1-\left(\frac{r}{p}\right)\right)\left(1-\left(\frac{s}{p}\right)\right) = \sum_{n}(-1)^{e+f+g+h}\sum_{p \leq X} \left(\frac{n}{p}\right)
$$
will be asymptotically at least $\pi(X)$."

I am having trouble understanding why the sum is asymptotically at least $\pi(X)$. This seems somewhat contradictory to me, as it appears to be the sum of functions which are asymptotically less than $\pi(X)$. Thanks!

Comment: Done, thanks for the suggestion and @YCor for the edit. I'm new to this site so it's all very helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the double sum on the right-hand side. If $n$ is a square, then $e+f+g+h$ is even, hence its contribution is asymptotically $\pi(x)$. If $n$ is not a square, then its contribution is $o(\pi(x))$. Hence if $k$ denotes the number of squares among the $16$ numbers $(-3)^eq^fr^sg^h$, then the double sum is $(k+o(1))\pi(x)$. However, $k$ is at least $1$, because $n=1$ is a square. So the double sum is asymptotically at least $\pi(x)$.